# How can i get the related data via the model?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I want to simply have a loop which have a sub-loop with all of the images link to the `project. project.id = images.model_key` in my case.

So i was trying to do something which didn't work.

```
function index()
    {
    $projects = Project::all();
    foreach($projects as $project)
        {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($project->images);
        echo "</pre>";
        }
    }
```

Im the project model.

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\ProjectCategoryProject;
use App\Models\Image;

class Project extends Model

{

    public $fillable = ['id', 'title','description', 'home_page', 'display'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProjectCategoryProject');
    }


    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Image');
    }

...
```

So i guess i have to specify in the model that `project.id = images.model_key` but how ?

Error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'images.project_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `images` where `images`.`project_id` = 4 and `images`.`project_id` is not null)
Thanks, sorry i'm guetting confused.
```

Comment: That error says everything you need.. do you have the `project_id` column on the `images` table?

Comment: No i have the model_key column which is equal to project_id.

Comment: @CREAZPRO though that is equal, you need to have a coloumn name as project_id in your images table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Laravel tries to guess the column name from current model, so in a model Project it will presume the column for it's ids in other models to be project_id. You can however override this and explicitly specity the columns to use for relationship:

```
public function images()
{
    // specify a foreign key to use
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Image', 'model_key'); 
}
```

Or this if you wanna be fully explicit.

```
public function images()
{
    // specify a foreign key to use
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Image', 'model_key', 'id'); 
}
```

I would however strongly encourage you to abide by laravel "convention" for better readability and easier maintenance. If possible, just rename the column :).